# Python binary search algorithmn returns None

Tags: python

So i tried to do binary search in python, which i think syntactically right, but logically somewhere going wrong, despite of checking it infinite times. Here is my code.

```
def m(a,ele):
    a=a
    ele=ele

    length = len(a)
    if length <=1:
        return a
    mid = a[length//2]

    if ele == mid:
        return True
    elif ele > mid:
        print("if")
        if len( a[a.index(mid):]) == 0:
            return False
        elif len( a[a.index(mid):]) ==1 and ele !=  a[a.index(mid):]:
            return False
        elif len( a[a.index(mid):]) ==1 and ele ==  a[a.index(mid):]:
            return True
        else:
            m( a[a.index(mid):],ele)
    else:
        print("else")
        if len( a[:a.index(mid)]) == 0:
            return False
        elif len( a[:a.index(mid)]) ==1 and ele !=  a[:a.index(mid)]:
            return False
        elif len( a[:a.index(mid)]) ==1 and ele ==  a[:a.index(mid)]:
            return True
        else:
            m( a[:a.index(mid)],ele)


print(m([1,3,6,8],8))
```

SO, in this case it should print True but it is printing None. Any help regarding this code would be helpful, i know i am doing some silly mistakes.

Comment: You need to return the result of recursion. i.e: `return m( a[a.index(mid):],ele)`

Comment: ahhhhh, Such a silly mistake! thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of each step of recursion. (In all the else's)

```
else:
       return m( a[a.index(mid):],ele)
```

Answer (score 1):

THank you people for correcting me. So this is my final code

```
def m(a,ele):
    a=a
    ele=ele

    length = len(a)
    if length <=1:
        return a
    mid = a[length//2]

    if ele == mid:
        return True
    elif ele > mid:
        if len( a[a.index(mid):]) == 0:
            return False
        elif len( a[a.index(mid):]) ==1 and ele !=  a[a.index(mid):][0]:
            return False
        elif len( a[a.index(mid):]) ==1 and ele ==  a[a.index(mid):][0]:
            return True
        else:
            return m( a[a.index(mid):],ele)
    else:
        if len( a[:a.index(mid)]) == 0:
            return False
        elif len( a[:a.index(mid)]) ==1 and ele !=  a[:a.index(mid)][0]:
            return False
        elif len( a[:a.index(mid)]) ==1 and ele ==  a[:a.index(mid)][0]:
            return True
        else:
            return m( a[:a.index(mid)],ele)


print(m([1,3,6,8,77,777],777))
True
```